# Kingfisher images resizing before loading?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, kingfisher

I load my images in a tableview using:

```
        let imageSize: CGFloat = 125.0
        let processor = RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: 10)
        let placeholder = UIImage(color: .gray, size: CGSize(width: imageSize, height: imageSize))

        cell.imageView?.kf.indicatorType = .activity
        cell.imageView?.kf.setImage(with: url!, placeholder: placeholder, options: [.transition(.fade(0.2)), .processor(processor)])
        cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Although what seems to happen is that images are larger than what they were set (125.0) for a second and then get resized correctly once loaded. I'm assuming it's taking the size of the tableView cell which is:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
    }
```

Although, I just need my images to be 125.0 the entire time. Any help?

Comment: You can try to download all necessary images before loading tableview and to check whether it will help. Also, it's not necessary to touch imageview's layer at all.

Comment: I think downloading the images before loading the tableview is counter-intuitive to using Kingfisher in the first place.